# Keycode returns undefined and which returns 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keypress

I am working on keypress events.I am using Safari browser and looking for a functioanlity which works on any browser. But the e.keyCode always return undefined and e.which always returns 0. Please find code beloe:

```
$("a,input,button,select,textarea").live('blur',
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var key= e.keyCode || e.which;
        console.log(key);
});
```

Could any one suggest whats wrong in this code? I want get key code for keypress events.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Both of the properties is deprecated, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Answer (score 2):

You bind selectors to the wrong event - you should use something like `keypress` to catch keypress events

```
$("a,input,button,select,textarea").live('blur keypress'
  function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'keypress') {
      e.preventDefault();
      var key= e.keyCode;
      console.log(key);
    }
    if (e.type == 'blur') {
      e.preventDefault();
      // do smthg
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Can we include the keypress event inside blur event? can you please suggest?

Comment: The event order is `keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup`... `blur` is totally unrelated to keys... `blur` is when the focus is lost on an input.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette - I know, I just answered what was asked. I assume that OP wants to know if focus was lost on pressing the tab key or arrow etc

Comment: @mini i have tried that but still the value is coming as 0. :( any other suggestions please?

Comment: @stackaccount: I upvoted... My comment was for OP. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette basically when blur happens because of key press i want to do some thing. Like left and right key if blur happens for a key i want to something there. Could you or mini suggest please?

Comment: Then use `.on("keydown", function(e){` and test all keys that may have that effect. Left/right arrows are e.which 37 and 39. Use `console.log(e.which);` to find the other. By the way, `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9. The `blur` event does not have the `.which` attribute. -- I suggest `keydown` because if you want to "prevent" the action, you can `return false;`.

Comment: but i want to see if blur was happened because of  left arrow .. how can i do that? could you please provide an example? please @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: Without preventing it? just know it?

Comment: just provide an example. i will work on remaining please @LouysPatriceBessette

Comment: @stackaccount: Go ahead with this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/Vyxdmy?editors=1011) The `setTimeout()` is to "wait a little" to test if still on focus. ;)

Comment: @mini: You can use my example to complete your answer... ;)

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette - thats a neat way to solve that, but I wont use that in my answer - you better do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You wish to detect if an input lost focus dues to a key...

The thing is that the `blur` event is not related to keys at all. That an event that occurs when an input loses focus.

Even if the "cause" of the focus lost looks to be a "tab", it isn't for the event point of view.

On key hit, several events occur:

1. `keydown`
2. `keypress`
3. `keyup`

The blur then occurs, if the key is a "tab", because the browser does that for you. It not the direct effect from the key.

So the `blur` occurs after and doesn't carry the key `.which` information.

**Now to detect if an input has lost focus due to a key**, you have to "wait a little" and test if the input where there was a key event still is in focus.

To disable a particular key (and its effect), the `keydown` event is prefered, since the key has not been "printed" yet. It's time to `return false`.

```js
$("input,textarea").on('keydown', function(e) {
  //e.preventDefault();
  var that = $(this);
  var key = e.which;
  console.clear();
  console.log(key);
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(that.is(":focus")){
      console.log("Input still in focus.");
    }else{
      console.log("Input lost focus.");
    }
  },10);
  
  // To disable a key
  if(key==70){  // key "f"
    console.log("That funny letter is forbidden");
    return false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Try keyboard arrows, tab.<br>
The letter "f" is disabled... For fun.<br>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something!"><br>
<br>
<textarea placeholder="Type something!"></textarea>
```